# Distributional derivative of a hölder function

Tags: distribution-theory, holder-spaces

Let $f$ be a $\alpha$-Hölder function in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Question : does it have distributional derivatives in a $L^p$ space ? (modulo a suitable relationship between $\alpha$ and $n$).

I know the other way around : if we look at elements of Sobolev spaces, then we get a Hölder regularity depending on the dimension $n$ and exponent $p$. Is there a converse there ?
When I tried googling the question, I only found an article with an example of nowhere differentiability in the classical sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an easy example, take the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), which is Hölder for exponents small enough.

If you want a more elaborate example, take [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve) or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) function, which are not Lipschitz, but are Hölder for every exponent less than $1$ for careful choices of the parameters (they are is actually quasi-Lipschitz). However they are not BV, so their distributional derivative cannot be in any Sobolev space.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I wasn't clear on the properties of BV functions. what if I add the property that $n=2$ and $f$ is subharmonic (and let's say $1/2$ hölder) ? could such a function have a distributional derivative not in $L_{\mathrm{loc}}^1$ ?

Comment: You could just forget BV and look at the first example: the Cantor function is, I think, one of the most famous examples of function for which there is no function which you could call its derivative.